# Variadic Generics in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, generics, variadic

### Context

Trying to have a generic "Observer" pattern in Delphi, I managed to make something working:

```
  TObserver = class
  protected
    FSubject: TSubject;
  public
    constructor Create(); virtual; overload;
    constructor Create( constref subject: TSubject ); virtual; overload;
    destructor Destroy(); virtual;
    procedure ReAttach( constref newSubject: TSubject ); virtual;
    procedure Update(constref subject: TSubject); virtual;
  end;

  TSubject = class
  protected
    FObservers: TList<TObserver>;
  public
    constructor Create; overload;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Notify(); virtual;
    procedure Attach(constref AObserver: TObserver); virtual;
    procedure Detach(constref AObserver: TObserver); virtual;
  end;
```

Every new Callback signature require to extend both the TSubject and TObserver. This quickly become tedious.

```
TMyObserver = class( TObserver )
public
  type TCallback = procedure (...) of object;
private
  FCallback: TCallback;
public
  property Callback: TCallback read FCallback write FCallback;
  procedure Update(constref subject: TSubject, ...); overload;
end;

TMySubject = class( TSubject )
...
```

This is not practical, so I wonder if there is a better approach.

For example, in C++, there are what are called `Variadic Templates` which would probably be called somehow `Variadic Generics` in Delphi?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename ...UpdateArgs>
class Observer
{
public:
    using CallbackType = std::function<void(UpdateArgs...)>;
    
    CallbackType callback;
    
    void Update(UpdateArgs... args)
    {
        if (callback) callback(args...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Observer<int, const std::string&> obs1;
    obs1.callback = [](int vInt, const std::string& vStr)
    {
        std::cout << "Int is: " << vInt << " and String is: '" << vStr << "'" << std::endl;
    };
    obs1.Update(42, "Hi you");
    
    // OR
    
    Observer<float> obs2;
    obs2.callback = [](float f)
    {
        std::cout << "Float is: " << f << std::endl;
    };
    obs2.Update(3.1415926);

    return 0;
}
```

[Test it live here](https://onlinegdb.com/ZQPvtPTOb)

For those not very fluent with C++, this basically is a generic `Observer` with a variable number of arguments. Making the callback available for the exact types and number of arguments required.

### Question

Does Delphi have Variadic Generics? that is, a way of specifying a variable set of arguments, allowing to specialize `TObserver` and `TSubject` for each required notification signature.

I would like the solution to be type-safe.

Otherwise, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

> Does Delphi have Variadic Generics?

No, it does not.  Everything Generics can do is fully documented on Embarcadero's DocWiki:

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Generics_Index